# Inconsistent behavior yticklabels subplot in factorplot using seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, seaborn

When I run the code from the Seaborn API:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet",data=exercise)
```

I get the following image: 
[image]

However, the image attached to the example in the [API](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html) looks like this:

[image]

, in which the yticks of the right plot are not visualized.

Is there a way to make sure that for my own plot the yticks for the right plot are not visualized?

I'm using:

- Seaborn 0.8.1.
- Pandas 0.21.0
- Matplotlib 2.1.0
- Scipy 1.0.0
- Numpy 1.13.3

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code you have posted works for me on version 0.8

Comment: Weird. Maybe a bug then? Or matplotlib dependency issue?

Comment: Perhaps. Can you include versions of relevant packages i.e. matplotlib, pandas (if you have it installed) etc

Comment: Included in the question above.

Comment: Starting a fresh install with all the version you have listed above, I now _can_ reproduce the issue

Comment: So which dependency is different in your case? Using conda to keep everything aligned.

Comment: I don't know why, but upgrading to `matplotlib 2.1.1` solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

As [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851928/davidg) illustrated, this is (probably) due to a dependency issue with matplotlib. Upgrading matplotlib resolved this 'buggy' behavior.

If you're using `conda`, this can be simply done by:

```
conda upgrade matplotlib
```

Or if you want to upgrade to a specific version:

```
conda install matplotlib=2.1.1
```